Python parallelism and /dev/ttyS0 sharing
I don't know how to make those two functions (which are called in the code below at the end) parallel. If I do multitasking or multiprocessing I came across errors regarding multiple port access. If I use mutexes I come across issues regarding deadlocks - I tried to wrap the contents of those infinite whiles with locks but then everything stalled, then I tried to add within the GSM class mutex wrappers, but again, deadlocks, deadlocks and deadlocks. I have even tried to use asyncs but no success since I had troubles with the lack of await in serial_digest function. I don't know how to overcome this issue.
Note: I know that there is a lot of code, but I think that all of it is necessary and is not quite difficult to read, even if I am not a master at clean coding by far, especially regarding python.
import serial
from time import sleep
from gotify import Gotify

ctrlZ = chr(26)

gsm = {
        'check':'AT',
        'sig_quality':'AT+CSQ',
        'ready':'AT+CPIN?',
        #tech details
        'manufacturer':'AT+CGMI',
        'model':'AT+CGMM',
        'imsi':'AT+CIMI',
        'iccid':'AT+CCID',
        'net_reg_stat':'AT+CREG?',
        'scan_networks':'AT+COPS=?',
        'apn':'AT+CGDCONT?',
        'operator':'AT+COPS?',
        #tackling with GSM
        'check_sms':'AT+CMGF=1',
        'list_sms':'AT+CMGL="ALL"',
        'dial_last':'ATDL',
        'hangup':'ATH',
        'find_number':'AT+CNUM',
        'answer':'ATA',
    }

for key, value in gsm.items():
    gsm[key] = value + '\n'


class GSM:
    def __init__(self, port='/dev/ttyS0', baudrate=115200):
        self.ser = serial.Serial(port, baudrate)
    
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.ser.close()

    def transceive(self, message):
        self.ser.write(message.encode())
        self.ser.read_until()

    def receive(self):
        return self.ser.read_until().decode()[:-2]

    def auto_answer(self, accept):
        self.transceive('ATS0=' + accept + '\n')

    def dial(self, number):
        self.transceive('ATD' + number + ';\n')

    def send_sms(self, number, text):
        self.transceive('AT+CMGS=' + '"' + number + '"' + '\n' + text + ctrlZ)

    def unlock_enable(self, status):
        if status:
            val = '1'
        else:
            val = '0'
        self.transceive('AT+CFUN=' + val + '\n')
        while True:
            answer = self.receive()
            if answer == '+CPIN: SIM PIN':
                print('Modem powered!')
            elif answer == 'OK':
                break

    def unlock_sim(self, pin):
        self.transceive('AT+CPIN=' + pin + '\n')
        while True:
            response = self.receive()
            if response == 'ERROR':
                raise Exception('Incorrect PIN!')
            elif response == 'OK':
                print('SIM activated!')
                break

    def wait(self, delay):
        self.transceive('WAIT=' + delay + '\n')


def init(g, pin):
    g.transceive(gsm['ready'])
    if g.receive() != '+CPIN: READY':
        g.unlock_enable(True)
        g.unlock_sim(pin)
    sleep(3)
    g.transceive(gsm['check_sms'])
    while True:
        response = g.receive()
        if response == 'ERROR':
            print('Cannot send SMS!')
            break
        elif response == 'OK':
            print('Ready for sending SMS!')
            break


def serial_spit():
    pin = '0000'
    number = '0744604883'

    with GSM() as g:
        cmd = input('If you would like to set the PIN press nothing but the return key.\n')
        if cmd == '':
            pin = input('Please, introduce the PIN.\n')
        init(g, pin)

        while True:    
            cmd = input(f'''Introduce the command:
                        c - change the phone number (now it is {number} )
                        d - dial
                        h - hangup
                        m - message\n\n''')
            if cmd == 'c':
                number = input('Please, introduce the phone number you would like to use from now on.\n')
            elif cmd == 'd':
                g.dial(number)
            elif cmd == 'h':
                g.transceive(gsm['hangup'])
            elif cmd == 'm':
                txt = input('Please, introduce the next message.\n')
                if txt == '' :
                    continue
                g.send_sms(number, txt)
            else:
                print('Command not recognized')
    

def serial_digest():
    last_dialing_number = 0

    gotify = Gotify(
            base_url='http://localhost:80',
            app_token='A_8APqsvE8C5Rom',
    )
    
    with GSM() as g:
        while True:
            call_status = ''
            data = g.receive()

            if data == 'RING':
                call_status='Ring'
                g.transceive('AT+CLCC\r\n')
                data = g.receive()
                if data.startswith('+CLCC'):
                    for x in data[len('+CLCC: '):-len('\r\n')].split(','):
                        if x.startswith('"') and x.endswith('"'):
                            last_dialing_number = x.strip('"')
                gotify.create_message(
                    message=call_status,
                    title=last_dialing_number,
                )
                print(last_dialing_number)
                print(call_status)
                print()
            elif data == 'NO CARRIER':
                call_status='Hang'
                gotify.create_message(
                    message=call_status,
                    title=last_dialing_number,
                )
                print(last_dialing_number)
                print(call_status)
                print()
            elif data.startswith('+CMT'):
                [number,_,date,hour] = [x.strip('"') for x in data[len('+CMT: '):-len('\r\n')].split(',')]
                message = g.receive()
                message += '\n' + date + ' ' + hour
                title = number[2:]
                print(title)
                print(message)
                print()
                gotify.create_message(
                    message=message,
                    title=title,
                )

serial_spit()
serial_digest()


"/dev/ttyS0 sharing" at file-descriptor level is not advisable. The device node /dev/ttyS0 is for a serial terminal which typically connects to a RS-232 port. That is for a serial link that is point-to-point. In your case the connected device is a GSM modem. What makes you think this device can handle "sharing"? If you insist on "sharing" a serial link, then IMO the robust/reliable solution would involve a dedicated thread to handle/coordinate all I/O for this serial terminal. Essentially that's how every other "shared" device (e.g. mass storage, networking) is handled by the OS.

It's not about the device itself, but the communication. I want to be able to both send and receive messages from my GSM module, i.e., I'm trying to do kina a raspberry pi phone. To achieve this I need to be able to both read and write data over the serial interface. I don't want to stick with threads, but so far, they are the only viable solution for this situation IMO.

You can have a thread just for sending to the GSM modem, and another just for receiving. The typical serial terminal is full duplex; you can send and receive simultaneously and independently. But the typical high-level protocol does not treat TxD and RxD so independently.

True that, I have just discovered this important feature. This kinda saved me.
